# ItextSharp set field of a table from template pdf using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have PDF template.
In PDF template there is a table with the list of people with the columns name (name_dic) and surname (surname_dic). The field names are the same for all row.

With

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("NAME_DIC", "Lucas");

stamper.AcroFields.SetField("SURNAME_DIC", "Brown");
```

I write in the first line
How do I write in the second row?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solution.

first row

Stati_Famiglia[0].#subform[0].details[0].detail[0].NAME_DIC[0]

second row

Stati_Famiglia[0].#subform[0].details[0].detail[1].NAME_DIC[0]